# Write value to column if row string contain column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains many pre-defined column names. One column of this dataframe contains the name of these columns.

I want to write the value 1 where the string name is equal to the column name.

For example, I have this current situation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(0,index=[0,1,2,3],columns = ["string","a","b","c","d"])
df["string"] = ["b", "b", "c", "a"]


string  a   b   c   d 
------------------------------
b       0   0   0   0
b       0   0   0   0
c       0   0   0   0
a       0   0   0   0
```

And this is what I would like the desired result to be like:

```
string  a   b   c   d 
------------------------------
b       0   1   0   0
b       0   1   0   0
c       0   0   1   0
a       1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) on `df['string']` and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the DataFrame in place:

```
df.update(pd.get_dummies(df['string']))
```

updated `df`:

```
  string  a  b  c  d
0      b  0  1  0  0
1      b  0  1  0  0
2      c  0  0  1  0
3      a  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
df.loc[ df[“column_name”] == “some_value”, “column_name”] = “value”
```

In your case

```
df.loc[ df["string"] == "b", "b"] = 1
```